# Disclosable view with autolayout in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, autolayout

I am writing a Cocoa application using autolayout directly from the source code. The NSWindow contents are not stored in a NIB file. I want this application to have a disclosable view where less used controls will be added. So the desired outcome is to have a button that, when clicked, will expand the NSWindow to reveal the extra view. Currently I am trying to animate the constraint that has the width of the disclosable view, but that keeps the NSWindow width constant and instead rearranges the views within. How should I be doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you want an NSClipView in between, this way you would resize the clip view. it's content would not be affected because the NSClipView would clip off the parts that don't fit.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at what was done with NSStackView in the Apple sample code for that new view. It is exactly a disclosable view design based on auto layout.